# "Not equivalent to" in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I want to do a $\Longleftrightarrow$ with a dash over it, indicating "A is NOT equivalent to B", but $\not \Longleftrightarrow$ does not center the dash. This looks ugly. Are there other solutions?

Comment: "equivalence" exists as `$\equiv$`, for which `$\not\equiv$` might be suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`centernot` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/centernot) provides this functionality:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{centernot}

\begin{document}

$A \Longleftrightarrow B \centernot{\Longleftrightarrow} C$

\end{document}
```

Reference: [How to negate a specific symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140996/5764)